# Autofit swapped image with Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

```
//The line below gets the tag type, in this instance, it's the image tag <img>
var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
//This is where the magic happens. We start by setting up the concept
for (var i = 0, l = imgs.length; i < l; i++) {
//This is where we replace imgs (the variable that gets the image tag), gets the requirements with     "[i]", and replaces the images met by the requirements with the src (source link)
imgs[i].src = "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-KL7d7LdSANg/Tm5VLQf9k4I/AAAAAAAAACo/cSV52JoD7vk/s1600/cat-wallpaper-34-713472.jpg";
}
```

I'm looking to autofit then autocrop the new image after the pages are loaded. The cat fills the image, but it squishes it. Javascript is what I'm assuming I'll use.

Comment: The image link is the cat.

Comment: Why is the cat being squished :(.

Comment: I meant that the cat picture squishes, not the actual cat XD.

Comment: Lol, I can't see a cat in your post ; ). How would you know, where the cat is positioned on the image, so you could crop it? A simple cross-browser way would be to wrap the images to a sized `div`s set `overflow:hidden` and then position the images to a correct position within the `div`s.